# Bind android custom view to a specific layout xml (is this even possible?)

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I'd like to put a custom view multiple times in my main.xml which consists of a RelativeLayout, some controls and then my custom view.
This custom view should use the following (simplified) xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="220px"
android:layout_height="220px"
android:background="@drawable/contextitemshape">
<TextView
    android:text="some caption"
    android:textSize="23px"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I get it to use this file each time it is created? Is that even possible in android? All the custom views I can find don't use an own layout-xml file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your custom `View` inflate the layout as part of its setup. [Here is a project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer) that, among other things, implements a `ColorMixer` custom `View` that inflates a layout containing three `SeekBar` widgets and some other stuff.

Comment: Thank you! Its probably important to note that one has to extend a layout instead of a view. At least I can't get the LayoutInflater to work when extending View.

Comment: @ShadowMare: Yes, you need an actual container class for the inflation technique I demonstrate to work. In your case, you might have your custom `View` extend `RelativeLayout` and use `<merge>` to bring in the rest of your contents.